# Which ActiveX controls are used by an application?

Tags: windows-xp, activex

Is there an easy way to figure out which ActiveX controls are used by an application on a Windows XP box?

Answer (score 2):

Dependency Walker might be a good place to start:
http://www.dependencywalker.com/.